# My question is about diabled apps that my husband diabled

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

My apps including some of green robots have been disabled and I don't know how to restore. My space for new apps is messed up also. Help

Comment: Go to Settings-> Apps-> select disabled app. Tap on ENABLE button, to enable them.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what phone you are using but usually you have to go to Settings, then Apps, and there, you can filter by "All apps" and see which ones are disabled(and then enable them), or you can filter by "Disabled".

If you don't see these options, maybe you could install some package disabler from the Play store that can list disabled apps. Just look for one that doesn't ask for too many permissions.
There's one called "Disable Bloatware - Hide Apps" that may be useful to you.